# Exim restrict send emails only from predefined list of emails

Tags: linux, email, hosting, spam, exim

I use Exim MTA. I need to restrict hosting (lamp) send emails only from predefined list **"From:"** emails per user to prevent massive spam if website was hacked.

Users use php to send emails via builtin function **mail();**

Eg. user **client1** have domain **example.org** and in cms settings configured to send emails From **info@example.org**. Any other sender From i need to reject for this user. But users need ability to configure multiple From emails.

How implement this in exim?

Currently i have simple acl to block entire user emails by this ACL:

```
acl_check_not_smtp:
    deny
        condition = ${lookup{$sender_ident}lsearch{/etc/exim4/restricted_sender}   {yes}}
```

And **/etc/exim4/restricted_sender** is simple list of users:

```
client1
```

Thanks.